# How can I change the type of a Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, json, object, prototype

I am building a webpage-based text adventure game, like Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy or the Zork series. I save objects in this game, like locations or player data, in localStorage, so that the player can continue their progress.

I am using [CircularJSON](https://github.com/WebReflection/circular-json) to stringify my circular references within these objects in order to save them.

However, when these objects are parsed, they are of the default **Object** type.

This is a problem because the functions in types like **Area**:

```
var Area = function (tempdescription, tempinitialDesc, tempobjArr) {
    this.isExplored = false;
    this.description = tempdescription;
    this.objArr = tempobjArr;
    this.paths = [];
    this.initialDesc = tempinitialDesc;
};
Area.prototype.getIndex = function (tempstr) {
    if(thePlayer.playerLocation.objArr.length > 0) {
        for(var i = 0; i < thePlayer.playerLocation.objArr.length; i++) {
            if(thePlayer.playerLocation.objArr[i].name.indexOf(tempstr) != -1) {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
};
```

or **Player**:

```
var Player = function (defaultLocation) {
    this.inv = []; // an array of game objects
    this.playerLocation = defaultLocation; // the player's current location
    this.moveCount = 0;
    this.score = 0;
};

Player.prototype.getIndex = function (tempstr) {
    if(thePlayer.inv.length > 0) {
        for(var i = 0; i < thePlayer.inv.length; i++) {
            if(thePlayer.inv[i].name.indexOf(tempstr) != -1) {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
};
```

which were created by me, need to be present in each object order for my other code to work.

I need to change the type of several objects in a simple way, if it exists, because when I save these objects there will probably be several dozen of them by the time the game is done.

Is there any way to change the type of a Javascript object?

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to SO. You should check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your question. Consider adding example code and what you've tried.

Comment: I added some code and I haven't tried anything yet, because I don't know where to start. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Start with searching: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+change+object+type then trying, then ask when failing?

Comment: I'd say those answers are pretty outdated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option #1 (using ES2015):** `const newObject = Object.setPrototypeOf(oldObject, Player.prototype)`

This is pretty slow though, check the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf):

> Warning: Changing the [[Prototype]] of an object is, by the nature of how modern JavaScript engines optimize property accesses, a very slow operation, in every browser and JavaScript engine.

That's an alternative to...

**Option #2 (deprecated):** `oldObject.__proto__ = Player.prototype`

**Option #3:** `const newObject = new Person(/* Use the properties of oldObject */)`

Comment: What does "const" mean, how is it different from "var"?

Comment: That's a completely different question. For the purposes of changing an object's type, you can use whatever you like, either `const`, `let`, or `var`. They're ES2015/ES6 features. If you want to learn about them find an introduction to ES6 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const